# For which $\alpha\gt0, f(x) = \frac {\sin x}{x^\alpha}$ is integrable on $[1,+\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

For which $\alpha\gt0, f(x) = \frac {\sin x}{x^\alpha}$ is integrable on $[1,+\infty)$

This is what I try to do:

Let $u=\frac{1}{x^\alpha},\frac{du}{dx}=-\alpha x^{-\alpha-1}$ and $\frac{dv}{dx}=sinx,v=-cosx$

so $\int_1^\infty{f(x)} = -x^{-\alpha}cosx|_1^\infty+\int_1^\infty{(-cosx)(-\alpha x^{-\alpha-1})}$ but it seems not help on my problem...
Anyone has another way on this?

Comment: With Abel test  it converges for all $\alpha>0$.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Can we use that? Sin(x) is not convergence

Comment: Or by parts as i did below. thanks.

Comment: @JackyChong Sorry for confusing. It's Lebesgue

Comment: Is my answer correct?

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Your answer looks correct. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

By parts

with
$u=x^{-\alpha} $ and $v'=\sin(x)$,

the integral becomes

$$[-\frac{\cos(x)}{x^\alpha}]_1^{+\infty}-\alpha \int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^{\alpha+1}}dx$$

as $\alpha>0$, the first term goes to $\cos(1)$ and

since $\alpha+1>1$,

the second integral converges absolutly cause 
$$|\frac{\cos(x)}{x^{\alpha+1}}|\leq \frac{1}{x^{\alpha+1}}$$

thus, we conclude that our integral converges for all $\alpha>0$.

Comment: Why is the second integral converges? cos(x) is not converge right?

Comment: @梁楷葳 by comparison  test.

Comment: You said $|\frac{\cos(x)}{x^{\alpha+1}}|\leq \frac{1}{x^{\alpha+1}}$ but we need $\frac{\cos(x)}{x^{\alpha+1}}\leq \frac{1}{x^{\alpha+1}}$ isn't it?

Comment: Do you know comparison test .

Comment: @ Abdallah Hammam for$ a_{n}$ and$ b_{n}$,$a_{n}\le b_{n}$ if$ \sum b_{n}$ converge then $\sum a_{n} $converge? Is that right?

Comment: The comparison test for improper integrals.

Comment: @ Abdallah Hammam I am sorry, I still don't get it, why we can say that converge by absolute value smaller than $\frac{1}{x^{\alpha+1}}$

Comment: I got it now.....I misunderstanding something. Thank you!